# Request Sentinel1 data with sentinelhub API doesn't work

Tags: python, sentinel-1, jupyter-notebook, sentinel-hub

I'm trying to acess Sentinel1 images using sentinelhub API with Jupyter lab notebook.
I'm getting error messages and I don't understand why I get them.

This is how I try to acess umages with IW (as mentioned in the [documentation,](https://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/ogc_request.html) with specifcying asc or desc):

```py
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sentinelhub import MimeType, CRS, BBox, SentinelHubRequest, SentinelHubDownloadClient, \
    DataCollection, bbox_to_dimensions, DownloadRequest,WmsRequest, WcsRequest, MimeType



#define bbox:
bbox_coords_wgs84 = [-44.763, -6.782, -44.583, -6.896]
bbox = BBox(bbox=bbox_coords_wgs84, crs=CRS.WGS84)

#request:

s1_request = WmsRequest(
    data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL1_IW,
    layer='TRUE-COLOR-S1-IW',
    bbox=bbox,
    time=('2020-11-01','2020-12-06'),
    width=512,
    config=config
)

s1_data = s1_request.get_data()
plot_image(s1_data[-1])



>>>DownloadFailedException: Failed to download from: *link*   
with HTTPError:
400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: *long url*  

Server response: "Layer TRUE-COLOR-S1-IW not found"
```

I also tried specifying:

```
s1_asc_request = WmsRequest(
    data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL1_IW_ASC,
    layer='TRUE-COLOR-S1-IW',
    bbox=bbox,
    time=('2020-11-01','2020-12-06'),
    width=512,
    config=config
)

s1_asc_data = s1_asc_request.get_data()
plot_image(s1_asc_data[-1])

>>>---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2bc6f9148c34> in <module>
      9 
     10 s1_asc_data = s1_asc_request.get_data()
---> 11 plot_image(s1_asc_data[-1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know why I get thise errors; it seems like I do almost the same as in the tutorial. What is my mistake? Why do I get those errors?

My end goal: to be able to import Sentinel1 images (vh and vv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error mentions there is a layer missing in the Sentinel Hub configuration you are using to perform a WMS request.
See documentation on [how to configure your account](https://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/ogc_request.html#Sentinel-Hub-account) before using sentinelhub-py.

If I guessed correctly your SH credentials, I have added a new configuration with the instance ID:
"40575c18-d1b9-4a4a-MASKED"

Go to Configuration utiity to find the full ID:
https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/dashboard/#/configurations/

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am not sure is my credentials because I haven't seen it. If it relates to the configurations, then I can tell that I have created  sentinel1 configuration  (sentinel1 template configuration) , so i'm not sure if that what you said you did

Comment: To use sentinelhub-py out of the box, you will need to have "Python instance template".

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand, the Sentinel1 configuration is not good for retreiving sentinel1 images? I also don't have "python instance template" in the configurations. Does the sentinel1 configuration is only good for the bbox you have in the tutorial? i'm very confused...

Comment: sentinel-1 configuration is perfectly fine for retreiving sentinel-1 data. However, if you are using sentinelhub-py in the way you are using it, the libraries assume some very specific configuration and names of the layers (which are not the same as in Sentinel-1 configuration). If you do "Add new configuration" and then choose "select from existing instance", you can then choose "Python scripts template".